# Store option disabled in My Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I want to submit my app (WP8) on windows phone store, but my store options are disabled. Please provide any solution to publish my app.

[image]

Please help me to upload my app.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are not signed-in to your developer account.  Upper right corner of the VS main window, right below the close button.

Comment: Those options are only for wp8.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It appeared that the basic release build creates the needed files to add your app to the store.

Check `\Bin\Release` folder and look for `.xap` file (f.ex `MyApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap`). This is the package that you can submit. You can add it to the [Windows Phone Store](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/dashboard).